# Bilinear form and random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $(X,Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(m,\Sigma)$. How can I express $\mathrm{E}\left[ {}^t X Y \right]$ ?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian? You didn't provide any statistical relation between $X$ and $Y$ (and thus $EXY^T$ can't be calculated)...

Comment: Even in the case where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables (not a vector), we we can't express $\mathbb E(XY)$ only in terms of the mean and standard deviation of $X$ and $Y$. Indeed, we can consider $(X,Y)$ a Gaussian vector, where $m_X=m_Y=0$, $\Sigma_X=\Sigma_Y$ and $\operatorname{Corr(X,Y)=r$, where $0\leqslant r\lt 1$.

Comment: I also know that $(X,Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(m,\Sigma)$. Still, I don't see how I can compute $\mathrm{E} \left[ {}^t X Y \right]$.

Comment: First of all, you should edit your question with this new information. See @DavideGiraudo comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will also need the covariance. For any two random variables (not necessarily normal): $$\mathbb E(x y)=\operatorname{Cov}(x,y)+\mathbb E(x)\mathbb E(y)$$ whenever these moments exist.

Comment: Yes, thanks! But that formula doesn't hold if $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors, does it ?

Comment: It case be generalized in a straightforward way. Let $\mathbb E(x_i y_j)$ be a generic element of $\mathbb E(\mathbf x\mathbf y^T)$. Then, $$\mathbb E(x_i y_j)=\operatorname{Cov}(x_i,y_j)+\mathbb E(x_i)\mathbb E (y_j)$$ whenever these moments exist. Hence, $$\mathbb E(\mathbf x\mathbf y^T)=\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf x\mathbf y}+\mathbf{\mu}_\mathbf x\mathbf{\mu}_\mathbf y^T,$$ where $\mathbf{\Sigma}_{\mathbf x\mathbf y}$ is the covariance matrix and $\mathbf{\mu}_\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{\mu}_\mathbf y$ are the mean vectors.

Comment: Ok I understand ! But here, $X {}^t Y$ is a matrix whereas ${}^t X Y$ is a real valued random variable. I don't see how I can adapt your answer to my question.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by $t$?